# How to pass a state up the widget tree?

Tags: flutter

This is the structure of my code:

```dart
class SomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      Widget1(), // How to pass `FooPageState` to this widget?
      Widget2(), 
    );
  }
}


class Widget2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<Widget2> createState() => _Widget2State();
}

class _Widget2State extends State<Widget2> {
  final GlobalKey<FooPageState> _globalKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      InnerWidget1(),
      FooPage(
        key: _globalKey,
      ),
      InnerWidget2(
        pageState: _globalKey.currentState, // Passing `FooPageState`
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I need to pass `FooPageState` to `Widget1`, how can I do that? `FooPage` is just a regular `StatefulWidget` whose state is `FooPageState`.

**Some workarounds:**

1. Declare the `_globalKey` in the `SomePage` and pass it to both `Widget1` and `Widget2`.
2. Convert `SomePage` to `StatefulWidget`, define a callback in it, pass it to `Widget2` and then in a method like `SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`, invoke the passed callback, which can in turn call the defined `_SomePageState` callback with `setState` and pass the `FooPageState` to `Widget1`. The same thing can also be done using a `Notification` and `NotificationListener`.

Comment: can you provide the `FooPage`?

Comment: You can use `ValueListener`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74415447/how-to-change-selected-index-value-from-other-dart-file-of-another-dart-file , this might help.

Comment: @MNBWorld `class FooPage extends StatefulWidget` and `class FooPageState extends State<FooPage>`.

Comment: There could be multiple child of type FooPage for SomePage. How would you decide which one's state object should it receive?

Comment: @Rahul `FooPage` is just a normal widget, I'm not using it in a type and I actually didn't understand what you are trying to convey.

Comment: What do you mean by state in this context, do you mean the lifecycle  of `FooPage` or the local variables you are using in it.

Comment: @MohammedAlfateh I mean `FooPageState` state i.e. the state class which extends Flutter `State` class. I have some methods in `FooPageState` which I want to invoke.

Comment: Hi @iDecode sorry for the late reply, in this case I would recommend you to use a state management library so the method would be in state class and you can manipulate the state from any widget and also you can listing to the state in any widget, you can try [flutter_riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_riverpod).

Comment: @MohammedAlfateh No problem. I can use the riverpod but I need to pass state not data. (State can be considered data, but passing state to riverpod doesn't make much sense).

Comment: @iDecode you don't need to pass the state because the state will only live in the provider, instead you can trigger an event/method from other widgets to create or manipulate the state used in the "FooPage" screen, I can illustrate this with an example if you provide a specific scenario

Comment: @iDecode Is there anything that does not meet your requirements in my answer?

Comment: @offworldwelcome Sorry to say this but I actually didn't go through with your answer for two reasons. 1. It's way too long to do something so trivial. 2. You didn't use my use case.

Comment: @iDecode 1) The length is irrelevant because it's what was needed to achieve your requirements; this is a Flutter thing, not me deciding to make code long for my own pleasure. 2) You have no use case; the goal was to access some widget's state in another widget. I did exactly that and avoided your mentioned work-arounds. I also showed how to do it with riverpod which has a lot less boilerplate.

Comment: @offworldwelcome Can you use my example and do it using Riverpod? I'll be happy to accept the answer then.

Answer (score 2):

**Behavior:**

A widget with a button that can read and set the value of another widget's state. The counter is incremented on the state reader (not the state owner) and the changes are reflected in both widgets.

[image]

- This can be achieved by using an `InheritedWidget` because its data can be accessed by widgets below the `InheritedWidget` in the widget tree through `BuildContext`.
- Every step that follows contains a short description of the issue tackled and then the commented code with a fuller explanation of individual parts.

First, let's define our entry point; evident/trivial to understand.

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Scaffold(body: SharedStateWidget())));
```

Second, let's create a helper class that allows us to read/write `FooPageState`.

```
/// Helper class. In this case, the template parameter T will be [FooPageState].
class Data<T> {
  T? value;
}
```

Third, let's create the `SharedStateWidget` that allows access to `FooPageState` through the `InheritedWidget` class behavior.

```
/// Parent widget of any widget that must access [FooPageState].
class SharedStateWidget extends InheritedWidget {
  SharedStateWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key, child: const SomePage());

  /// The helper class is used to assign to [data.value], because this widget
  /// itself is immutable (won't rebuild).
  final Data<FooPageState> data = Data<FooPageState>();

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(SharedStateWidget oldWidget) {
    return data != oldWidget.data || data.value != oldWidget.data.value;
  }

  /// Ensure that this method is ONLY called by children of [SharedStateWidget],
  /// because the null-check operator `!` is used to avoid returning a nullable.
  static SharedStateWidget of(BuildContext context) =>
      context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<SharedStateWidget>()!;
}
```

Fourth is your `SomePage` widget that contains some other widget (in this case called `FooStateReceiver`), that wants to read `FooPageState`.

```
/// [SomePage] is a child of [SharedStateWidget], which is an [InheritedWidget].
/// Therefore, itself and its children can access [SharedStateWidget] through
/// the [SharedStateWidget.of] static method.
class SomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: const [
        /// [FooPageState] will be accessed through [SharedStateWidget.of].
        FooStateReceiver(),
        FooPage(),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Fifth comes the class that needs `FooPageState` to call some external operation on said state.

```
/// A widget that uses [FooPageState] to perform some external operation.
class FooStateReceiver extends StatefulWidget {
  const FooStateReceiver({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FooStateReceiver> createState() => _FooStateReceiverState();
}

class _FooStateReceiverState extends State<FooStateReceiver> {
  FooPageState? _fooState;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    /// The [SomePageInheritedWidget.of] cannot be called before [initState].
    /// Call [setState] so that this widget itself is rebuilt after reading
    /// [SharedStateWidget.data.value].
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (timeStamp) => setState(
        () => _fooState = SharedStateWidget.of(context).data.value,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 64.0,
      height: 64.0,
      child: FloatingActionButton(
        /// Updates this widget's state using the other widget's state.
        onPressed: () => setState(() => ++_fooState?.counter),
        child: Text(
          "${_fooState?.counter}",
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Sixth is the class whose state must be accessed by another widget, this is your `FooPage`.

```
/// This is the [StatefulWidget] whose state we want to access from
/// [FooStateReceiver].
class FooPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FooPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FooPage> createState() => FooPageState();
}

class FooPageState extends State<FooPage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  int get counter => _counter;

  /// The method that you want to call from [FooStateReceiver].
  /// Sets [_counter] if it is different from [value] and rebuilds.
  set counter(int value) {
    if (_counter == value) return;
    setState(() => _counter = value);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Set [data.value] of the [StateWidget] so that it can be used by
    /// [FooStateReceiver] whenever this widget is rebuilt.
    SharedStateWidget.of(context).data.value = this;

    return SizedBox(
      width: 64.0,
      height: 64.0,
      child: Align(
        child: Text("$counter", style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The exact same behavior using `riverpod`:

```
void main() => runApp(
    const MaterialApp(home: ProviderScope(child: Scaffold(body: SomePage()))));

class SomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: const [
        FooStateReceiver(),
        FooPage(),
      ],
    );
  }
}

final fooStateProvider = StateProvider<FooPageState?>((ref) => null);

class FooStateReceiver extends StatefulWidget {
  const FooStateReceiver({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FooStateReceiver> createState() => _FooStateReceiverState();
}

class _FooStateReceiverState extends State<FooStateReceiver> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 64.0,
      height: 64.0,
      child: Consumer(
        builder: (context, ref, child) {
          final fooState = ref.watch(fooStateProvider);

          return FloatingActionButton(
            /// Updates this widget's state using the other widget's state.
            onPressed: () => setState(() => ++fooState?.counter),
            child: Text(
              "${fooState?.counter}",
              style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FooPage extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const FooPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState<FooPage> createState() => FooPageState();
}

class FooPageState extends ConsumerState<FooPage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  int get counter => _counter;

  /// The method that you want to call from [FooStateReceiver].
  /// Sets [_counter] if it is different from [value] and rebuilds.
  set counter(int value) {
    if (_counter == value) return;
    setState(() => _counter = value);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    /// Update the provider state.
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (timeStamp) {
        ref.watch(fooStateProvider.notifier).state = this;
      },
    );

    return SizedBox(
      width: 64.0,
      height: 64.0,
      child: Align(
        child: Text("$counter", style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Conclusion:

- State management libraries will help/simplify the code necessary to achieve your desired behavior.
- You said that "You want the state, not data" in relation to using `riverpod`. However, state is like any other data/class.
- Separate your behavior from your UI. Look up the BLoC pattern for Flutter and implement it. It will clean up your code because UI code shouldn't implement complex data behavior in it.
- Animations might be an exception, but even those can be separated into their own data class.

Answer (score 0):

```
class SomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<FooPageState> _globalKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      Widget1(),
      Widget2(globalKey: _globalKey), // How to get `FooPageState` here?
    );
  }
}

class Widget2 extends StatefulWidget {
  final GlobalKey<FooPageState> globalKey;
  const Widget2({Key key, this.globalKey}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Widget2> createState() => _Widget2State();
}

class _Widget2State extends State<Widget2> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      InnerWidget1(),
      FooPage(
        key: widget.globalKey,
      ),
      InnerWidget2(
        pageState: widget.globalKey.currentState, // Passing `FooPageState`
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

how about this one.

```
FutureBuilder(
    future: Future.delayed(Duration.zero),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
    InnerWidget2(
        pageState: widget.globalKey.currentState, // Passing `FooPageState`
    )} else {
        return Container();
    }},
)
```

use futurebuilder or sameple input globalKey. then inInnerWidget2 just use globalKey after build.

Comment: by the time `pageState: widget.globalKey.currentState` will be invoked, the currentState will be null as flutter is still inside build method and state won't be attached to global key.

Comment: I commit new FutureBuilder, you can try it.

Answer (score 0):

you could just simply extend your class with the parent class state. like mentioned below.

```
class your_class_name extends State<your_state_widget> {}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).