# How to change selected index value from other dart file of another dart file?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having a very stupid problem.

So basically I have a custom bottom navigation bar. It was taking too much lines and indents in my `home.dart` file. So I decided to extract and place it in another dart file i.e. my `bottomnavbar.dart` file. 
And use it in my home page like this:

```
child: BottomNavBar(),
```

but I am having trouble in changing between screens in the home page. I am having this in my `home.dart` file:

```
int selectedIndex = 0;    
final screen = [
  PageOne(),
  PageTwo(),
  PageThree(),
  PageFour(),
  PageFive(),
];
```

Use:

```
///inside a stack
screen[selectedIndex],
```

and in my `bottomnavbar.dart` file I have extracted a widget for my bottom navigation bar `items`:

```
Widget bnbItems(
    String image,
    int index,
    double height,
  ) {
    return InkWell(
      splashColor: Colors.pink,
      onTap: () => setState(() {
        selectedIndex = index;
        _controller.animateTo(index / 4);
      }),
      child: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
          child: Image.asset(
            image,
            height: height,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Use:

```
Row(
  children: [
      bnbItems('assets/icons/icn1.png', 0, size.height / 25),
      bnbItems('assets/icons/icn2.png', 1, size.height / 21),
      bnbItems('assets/icons/icn3.png', 2, size.height / 19),
      bnbItems('assets/icons/icn4.png', 3, size.height / 34),
      bnbItems('assets/icons/icn5.png', 4, size.height / 21),
     ],
   ),
```

##### With this setup the `screens` are not changing. It happened since I moved the `BottomNavBar` to differnt file. 
Any solution? Maybe by using [GetX](https://pub.dev/packages/get)?

Comment: can you provide two sample widget that will reproduce the issue

Comment: Hi, does the `StatefulWidget` where the `SetState` is called contains that bottom nav bar or not, it seems that the nav bar id not included in a `StatefulWidget` where it's state will be updated when the `SetState` is called

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `setState` inside your `bottomnavbar.dart` you are only updating the StatefulWidget that is inside of that file, which is probably just the bottom navigation bar.

This is where you need shared state between two files, hence **state management**.

You could use `ChangeNotifier`, but for now start simple and use `ValueNotifier`

create a ValueNotifier for current screen in your home page

```dart
...

final ValueNotifier<int> currentScreen;

@override
Widget build(...
```

pass it to your bottom navigation widget

```dart
child: BottomNavBar(currentScreen),
```

add the ValueNotifier as a required field in your widget

```dart
class BottomNavBar extends StatelessWidget {
  const BottomNavBar({super.key, required this.currentScreen});

  final ValueNotifier<int> currentScreen;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
...
```

now you dont need `setState` in your bottom navigation bar, just edit the `currentScreen.value` in your `onTap`

```dart
onTap: () { 
        currentScreen.value = index;
        _controller.animateTo(index / 4);
      },
```

**Adjust the code per your project, these are just here as an example**

Comment: Didn't work, got some Problems. In `home.dart`, here `final ValueNotifier<int> currentScreen;` I am getting this error `The final variable 'currentScreen' must be initialized.
Try initializing the variable.`. In `child: BottomNavBar(currentScreen),`: got error this: `The named parameter 'currentScreen' is required, but there's no corresponding argument.
Try adding the required argument.` and this `Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.
Try removing the extra positional arguments, or specifying the name for named arguments.` I did exactly what you said to do.

Comment: those are basic stuff which are not related to your issue
`The final variable 'currentScreen' must be initialized` 
means that you haven't set a value for this field, just set a value right away when you declare it, final ValueNotifier<int> currentScreen = ValueNotifier(0);

the other issues are the basics of dart that you can easily find if you google them

Comment: Thanks mate, it worked perfectly. Actually I forgot to remove the `setstate`.